# Tapped event fires before DoubleTapped event in WinRT

Tags: xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I have the follwing declaration:

```
<Button Tapped="Handler1" DoubleTapped="Handler2" />
```

Each time I double tap the button the Handler1 gets fired. Handler 2 never gets fired.

Thanks.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. The DoubleTapped-handler works fine for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do in this way because it will always fire the first event of tap. You can manage the double tap with the single tap event using a boolean or a counter to manage the following tap events.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know why the DoubleTapped handler does not get called. It should. Maybe [IsDoubleTapEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.isdoubletapenabled) is set to false? This could not just happen by explicitly setting the property in XAML, but also e.g. by inheriting the value from a style.

But even when DoubleTapped works, the Tapped event will **always** fire once. The control is no fortune teller: When the first tap happens, it does not know that a second tap will soon follow, so it fires the Tapped event. If you do not want this, you need to implement your own behaviour and either ignore or delay Tapped events.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.doubletapped):

> If a user interaction also fires DoubleTapped, Tapped will fire first to represent the first tap, but the second tap won't fire an additional Tapped. If you want different logic for Tapped versus DoubleTapped, your Tapped handler may need to use app-specific variables and a timer in order to avoid running on interactions that are eventually interpreted as a DoubleTap action.

But using double taps is generally discouraged by the [UX guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465415). I would not use them with buttons, because buttons usually do not work that way and you are breaking user expectations.